# Where to put external Python Blender scripts when Blender was installed from Snap?

Tags: python

I wrote a Python script which uses Blender API and outputs render scene frame range. I want to execute it over a few files with no GUI/in the background. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447680/blender-open-and-parse-a-blend-file-from-python-script) thread which explains that I can put my script in ***path_to_blender/version/scripts/addons*** and later execute using `blender.exe --background myFile.blend --python ./version/scripts/addons/superScript.py`

The issue I'm having is that I don't know where to put my script as I installed Blender from Snap and so the file structure looks different. I found ***/snap/blender/current/2.83/scripts/addons*** but when trying to copy anything into it, it returns ***cp: cannot create regular file './get_scene_framerange.py': Read-only file system*** I also checked the following directories:

- /var/snap/
- /var/lib/snapd/
- /home/username/snap/

but only ***/snap/*** has dir called addons/

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

After talking to the guys on the official Blender forum #python it turned out the scrip can be located pretty much anywhere and it doesn't need to be in a special directory, as I thought before. To run it I used a command i.e: `blender --background monkey_test.blend --python ./get_scene_framerange.py` where the last bit is a path to the script located anywhere